# Seg fault on return static array in function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb

I tried to debug it by using gdb and "dissassemble", but it doesn't show the lines, just the function where it is getting Segmentation fault.

Here are the code :

It should check if the player has won (he is the last alive), or lost (he is not on the map anymore)

```
int * win_lose_verif(int number_of_player, int your_player);
```

It is the main loop, and I need it to stop whenever the player has won or lost

```
int network_fn(int number_of_player, int your_player);
```

The full code :

```
int * win_lose_verif(int number_of_player,int your_player) {
    int i;
    int j;
    int is_our_player_alive=0;
    int are_the_other_alive=0;
    int* condition_win_lose; //[0]lose condition [1]win condition

    condition_win_lose=(int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*2);        

    for (i=0; i<end_of_map_x-1; ++i) 
    {
        for (j=0; j<end_of_map_y-1; ++j) 
        {
            if (map[i][j] && (map[i][j]->species==P1||map[i][j]->species==P2||map[i][j]->species==P3||map[i][j]->species==P4) ) 
            {
                if(your_player==map[i][j]->species) //our player is here
                    is_our_player_alive++;
                else
                    are_the_other_alive++;
            }
        }
    }

    if(is_our_player_alive==0) {
        condition_win_lose[0]=1;
    }
    else {
        condition_win_lose[0]=0;
        condition_win_lose[1]=0;
        if(are_the_other_alive==0)
        {    condition_win_lose[1]=1;      }
    }       

    return condition_win_lose;

}



int network_fn(int number_of_player, int your_player) {
    int tick=0;
    int lose=0;
    int win=0;
    int* check_win_lose; // *(check_win_lose+0) for lose , +1 for win

    do {
        check_win_lose=win_lose_verif(number_of_player,your_player);

        if (*(check_win_lose + 0)==1) {
            return ENDGAME;
        }
        else if (*(check_win_lose + 1)==1) {
            return ENDWIN;
        }

    } while (1);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is what I get on gdb after a backtrace :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000403231 in win_lose_verif ()
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x0000000000403231 in win_lose_verif ()
#1  0x0000000000403cff in network_fn ()
#2  0x0000000000400db0 in main ()
```

I don't understand why I'm getting a segfault.

I don't get a segfault the first 20 seconds, but after that, I'm very likely to get it. Why?

EDITED : for the commentary that seems unclear. I tried to compile with ggdb, and still I'm not getting more info.
How can I make gdb print the line of the segfault ?

I changed the static into malloc

Comment: Compile with -g, set breakpoints in gdb, examine some variables, and test your assumptions

Comment: malloc the condition_win_lose array rather than trying to return a static scope array.

Comment: if using gcc for a compiler/linker,  then use the parameter -ggdb.  this will put the maximum amount of debug info into the executable.  -g is just simple debug info.  -ggdb adds extra info that gdb can use.

Comment: this comment: 'int* check_win_lose; // 0 for lose , 1 for win' does not match the actions of the following code

Comment: the array check_win_lose[] can only indicate if the current player is nolonger on the playing board.  It does not indicate the current player won, unless all the other players are missing from the board.  The posted code does not implement that logic

Comment: in the win_lose_verif() function, most of the action depends on a number of global variables.  My suspicion would be one or more of those global variables is corrupted.  the first passed parameter is not used, so the compiler raises a warning.  compile with all warnings enabled, then fix the warnings

Comment: @Alex Macklemore Try to clear the memory allocated once its usage overs in do-while loop. Try to run the program in gdb until it crash and use handle command for SIGSEGV. Might be it will help

Answer (score 0):

**By slowing down the process (A sleep in the while loop), the seg fault stopped.**

I can presume I was asking too much operations in a infinite loop, and made some overflow.

I don't know if this was the best answer, but that works fine for me. Be aware that infinite loop can be quite tricky if you ask too much operations.

Here is the final :

```
   do {
        sleep(1);
        check_win_lose=win_lose_verif(number_of_player,your_player);

        if (*(check_win_lose + 0)==1) {
            return ENDGAME;
        }
        else if (*(check_win_lose + 1)==1) {
            return ENDWIN;
        }

    } while (1);
```